# FFT loss in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to compute the loss between the GT and the output of my network (called TDN) in the frequency domain by computing 2D FFT. The tensors are of dim `batch x channel x height x width`

```
amp_ip, phase_ip = 2DFFT(TDN(ip))
amp_gt, phase_gt = 2DFFT(TDN(gt))
loss = ||amp_ip - amp_gt||
```

For computing FFT I can use [torch.fft(ip, signal_ndim = 2)](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.4.0/torch.html#torch.fft). But the output is in `a + j b` format i.e rectangular coordinates and NOT decomposed into phase and amplitude. How can I convert `a + j b` into `amp exp(j phase)` format in PyTorch? A side concern is also if `signal_ndims` be kept 2 to compute 2D FFT or something else?

The following description, which describes the loss that I plan to implement, maybe useful.

[image]

Comment: [This code file](https://github.com/YanchaoYang/FDA/blob/master/utils/__init__.py) will be useful. They find the amplitude and phase after getting the FFT of an image in PyTorch.

Comment: The code uses `torch.rfft` and another function also exists `torch.fft`. Is there any difference? Which one to use?

Comment: `rfft` takes only real-valued inputs (according to [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fft.html#torch.fft.fft)). The code I linked uses `rfft` since they have images as input that are inherently real-valued. You can decide based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered by the GITHUB code file shared by @akshayk07 in the comments. Extracting the relevant information from that code, the concise answer to the question is,

```
    fft_im = torch.rfft(img.clone(), signal_ndim=2, onesided=False)

    # fft_im: size should be bx3xhxwx2
    fft_amp = fft_im[:,:,:,:,0]**2 + fft_im[:,:,:,:,1]**2
    fft_amp = torch.sqrt(fft_amp) # this is the amplitude
    fft_pha = torch.atan2( fft_im[:,:,:,:,1], fft_im[:,:,:,:,0] ) # this is the phase
```

As of PyTorch 1.7.1 choose `torch.rfft` over `torch.fft` as the latter does not work off the shelf with real valued tensors propagating in CNNs. Also a good idea will be ti use the `normalisation` flag of `torch.rfft`.